# Zend Framework - 'LEV' currency not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, currency

I have the following code for the Bulgarian currency 'lev';

```
try
{
    $currency = new Zend_Currency("lev");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die;
}
```

Which throws an exception

> Currency 'lev' not found

How can I fix this, `USD` and `GBP` all work. Has this something to do with setting the correct Locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that BGN is the correct code, not LEV.

Detailed here as the ISO 4217 code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_lev

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass a locale to Zend_Currency, Try this.

```
$currency = new Zend_Currency('bg_BG');
```